# function and class calling

Tags: java, android, image

I currently have this code from some source and is it possible to call this function on onCreate?

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("mytag", "e");
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

I already tried:

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context);
public Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context);
public static getPickImageIntent(Context context);
```

but no luck. still have error calling the function.

And is it possible to call a 2nd.class from Main.class? 2nd.class has all the work and Main.class will just pass and retrieve the data, image and text?

Comment: What this `public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context)` . This is not the way you call a method . You just redefine them . To calling a method just use `getPickImageIntent(context)`  Where `context` is the argument in this case it can be `this` or any `Context`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I get this errors:
Error:(61, 13) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(61, 39) error: <identifier> expected
Missing method body, or declare abstract

Is it possible to put it on a button as onClick or anything? Tried onClick but got nothing.

Comment: Start https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any detailed info but I will try to assume/guess some of them and try to answer. For a future, please fix Your question and try to be as precise as possible.

> And is it possible to call a 2nd.class from Main.class? 2nd.class has all the work and Main.class will just pass and retrieve the data, image and text?

Yes, it is possible. Not exactly calling the class, but calling a method inside the class. If the method is static, You call it like this:

```
SecondClassName.methodName(parameter1, parameter2); // some method
SecpmdClassName.getPickImageIntent(context);        // method from Your question
```

If Your method is not static, You need an instance of Your class to call the method e.g:

```
SecondClassName secondClassInstance = new SecondClassName();
secondClassInstance.methodName(parameter1, parameter2);
secondClassInstance.getPickImageIntent(context); // You can also call a static method
```

You've mentioned a names like Main.class and 2nd.class. File names in Java needs to be equal to a public class declared inside. If this is Your class name "2nd" than it is incorrect. Classes' names cannot start with a digit - that's why I've used in my example above a "SecondClassName" instead of "2nd".

Comment: Sorry. It's originally Methods.class. i just used 2nd.class as a sample.

So i will put "SecondClassName.methodName(parameter1, parameter2);" on Main.class? i dont need anything to import?

Comment: If Your Methods class is in the same package as Main class then You don't need to add anything in import part. Otherwise You need:
import com.package.of.your.Methods;
and then it will be visible in Your Main class and it can be used.

Comment: So it will be import com.package.Methods on Main.class then.